How to write JOSM validator for detect duplicate addr:streetnumber?
I need to write check for duplicate addr:streetnumber in addr:street where is different addr:conscriptionnumber or addr:provisionalnumber. I wrote algoritm:
[addr:housenumber]=[addr:conscriptionnumber/addr:streetnumber].(CZ,SK)
[addr:housenumber]=[addr:provisionalnumber/addr:streetnumber].(CZ)
[addr:street][addr:streetnumber][addr:conscriptionnumber or addr:provisionalnumber] adresa_1, adresa_2
{if[addr:street+addr:streetnumber] in adresa_1 = in adresa_2 and [addr:conscriptionnumber or addr:provisionalnumber] in adresa_1 != in adresa_2;
throwWarning(“Duplicitní orientační číslo”);}
I guess it will not possible in MapCSS to compare tags between two elements, but in Python or Java will be able to. I’m not experienced in it, but I need to help for some bit learn how to do. Thanks!
I copied from address.java to build it, but it is so hard.
